# Laravel many to many relationship not working can anyone help me?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

Would any be so kind as to help me out? 
I am trying (in vain) to create a many to many relationship in laravel.
The database structure look good to me but relationship does not work.

I have 2 tables/models `users` and `competencies`
(one user, many users)
(one competency, many competencies)
1. fist off I created a database migration:

```php
class CreateCompetencyUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('competency_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('competency_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('competency_id')->references('id')->on('competencies');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('competency_user');
    }
}
```

2. setup 2
   linking the models
   in the `user` model i create a methode `competencies` and in the `Competency` model a methode `users`.

The documentation doesn't state anything else so this should be it right?

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',
        'is_admin' => 'bool',
        'is_super_admin' => 'bool'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'team_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'is_admin', 'is_super_admin'
    ];

    public function competencies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Competency::class,'competency_user','user_id','competency_id');
    }
}
```

```php
class Competency extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'icon', 'competency_set_id', 'card_image_da_id', 'order_value'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'competency_user', 'competency_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

after that when i run

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$user->competencies()->attach(4);
$user->save();
```

or

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$competency = Competency::find(4);
$user->competencies()->attach($competency);
$user->save();
```

nothing.....

i hope any one can help me out and that i have provide enough information
thx 
Maxim

edit:

migration: users

```php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(false);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

migration competencies

```php
class CreateCompetenciesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('competencies', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

            $table->string('icon');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->mediumText('description');
            $table->unsignedInteger('order_value')->default(99999);

            $table->unsignedInteger('competency_set_id');
            $table->foreign('competency_set_id')->references('id')->on('competency_sets');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('competencies');
    }
}
```

Comment: does it generate any error? and why your pivot table has "id" as primary key? can you please post the migrations also of users and competency?

Comment: sure no problem. 
the primary key: Habit I guess
and no i do not get any erros just no entry in the pivot table

Comment: Any log errors?

Comment: no nothing really strange

Comment: `composer du` done?

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is the problem, but it might be: in the `Competency` model the class related to the `users` relation, is `Users::class` where instead it should be `User::class`

Comment: thnx but that was a typo sorry.

Comment: well i think so that there is no Competency with id 4

Answer (score 0):

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
$competency = Competency::findOrFail(4);
dd($user->competencies()->attach($competency)->toSql());
//$user->save(); // <-- you don't need this, the attach() function already persists data in your DB
```

What does this code above return?

Comment: but    $user = User::find(1);
        dd($user->competencies()->toSql());

Comment: ]8;;file:///Users/maj/Documents/code/sites/api/tests/Feature/ClientUpdateProfileTest.php#L133\^]8;;\ "select * from `competencies` inner join `competency_user` on `competencies`.`id` = `competency_user`.`user_id` where `competency_user`.`competency_id` = ? and `competencies`.`deleted_at` is null"

Comment: this should be something like:

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM `competencies` c
INNER JOIN `competency_user` cu ON c.`id` = cu.`competency_id`
INNER JOIN `users` u ON cu.`user_id` = u.`id`